# Objective-C blocks usage

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have been looking around online, doing research into how to use blocks. I have also decided to set up a basic example to try and understand the way in which they work.

Essentially what I want to do is have a 'block variable' (no sure if thats the correct term) in which I can store a block of code. I then want to be able to set the code in this block at pointX (`methodA` or `methodB`) in my code, then run the block of code at pointY (`methodX`).

So to be specific, my question is 3-fold

1. Using the example below is the setup / usage of blocks correct and valid?
2. In `methodX` how do I execute the code inside the block (`self.completionBlock`)?
3. When creating the block in `methodA` and `methodB` will the code be called there and then? If so how can I stop this from happening (all I want to do is set up the code in the block to be called later)?

I may have completely misunderstood how blocks are used, apologies if this is the case, however I'm relatively new to Objective-C and I'm trying to learn.

Here is my code so far:

**.h**

```
typedef void (^ CompletionBlock)();

@interface TestClass : NSObject
{   
    CompletionBlock completionBlock;

    NSString *stringOfText;
    NSString *otherStringOfText;
}

@property(nonatomic, copy)CompletionBlock completionBlock;

@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *stringOfText;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *otherStringOfText;

- (void)methodA:(NSString *)myText;
- (void)methodB:(NSString *)myText and:(NSString *)myOtherText;
- (void)methodX;

@end
```

**.m**

```
- (void)methodA:(NSString *)myText;
{
    if ([self.stringOfText isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        // Set the variable to be used by the completion block
        self.stringOfText = @"I visited methodA"; // normally make use of myText

        // Create the completion block
        __block TestClass *blocksafeSelf = self;
        self.completionBlock = ^()
        {
            [blocksafeSelf methodA:blocksafeSelf.stringOfText];
            blocksafeSelf.stringOfText = nil;
        };
    }
    else
    {
        // Do some other stuff with self.stringOfText
    }
}

- (void)methodB:(NSString *)myText and:(NSString *)myOtherText;
{
    if ([self.stringOfText isEqualToString:@""] || [self.otherStringOfText isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        // Set the variable to be used by the completion block
        self.stringOfText = @"I visited methodB"; // normally make use of myText
        self.otherStringOfText = @"I also visited methodB"; // normally make use of myOtherText

        // Create the completion block
        __block TestClass *blocksafeSelf = self;
        self.completionBlock = ^()
        {
            [blocksafeSelf methodB:blocksafeSelf.stringOfText and:blocksafeSelf.otherStringOfText];
            blocksafeSelf.stringOfText = nil;
            blocksafeSelf.otherStringOfText = nil;
        };
    }
    else
    {
        // Do some other stuff with self.stringOfText and self.otherStringOfText
    }
}

- (void)methodX
{
    // At this point run the block of code in self.completionBlock...how?!
}
```

In my example either `methodA` or `methodB` will be called first. Then some time later (perhaps from a different class) `methodX` will be called (only ever after `methodA` or `methodB` have been called).

It's worth noting that the methods `methodA`, `methodB` and `methodX` are all in a singleton class.

**NOTE:** This is just a dummy example to try and understand the workings of blocks, I'm fully aware there are other ways to achieve the same result.

Comment: I have updated my question to be clearer....sorry!

Comment: Blocks appear simple, but have some non-obvious implications (such as retain cycles). A good place to start is "Advanced Mac OS X Programming" by Mark Dalrymple. Chapter 3 is a very good introduction to blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the code, just to be clear:

```
- (void)methodX
{
    if(self.completionBlock)
        self.completionBlock();
}
```

Comment: I guess people want copy and paste answers now a days ;)

Comment: I've run into programmers that would rather copy and paste than subclass. Then I get a bug after I fixed something in my class but not in the copy-paste implementation that I didn't even know about.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to do `self.completionBlock();` in `methodX`.

Comment: I agree with Mattias, but you should first check to verify that self.completionBlock is not NULL otherwise it will crash.